# How To Save These Nested Values in Parsed JSON Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, omniauth

Using Omniauth, I have the following in my custom strategy using oauth2, but only `uid` is being picked up and later saved in the User record.  The `email` and `name` in the info block are coming up as nil, despite having values  What is wrong with my info block?

**Omniauth Strategy.rb**

```
  uid do
    raw_info["user"]["uid"]
  end

  info do
    {
      email: raw_info["user"]["email"],
      name: raw_info["user"]["name"]
    }
  end

  def raw_info
    @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/v1/user').parsed
  end
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
   user: {
      uid: 1,
      email: "testusera1@example.net",
      name: null
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this appears to be working.